# Using abline() when x-axis is date (ie, time-series data) on zoo plot or a time series plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo

I want to add multiple vertical lines to a time series plot. 
Normally you would specify abline(v=x-intercept) but my x-axis is in the form 01/08/2000 – 31/07/2001. How would I adapt the abline code to add vertical lines for example 13/10/2000 and 30/05/2001?

Firstly, I have tried the following zoo plot but the x-axis is not giving me the preferred date format;

```
dat<-read.table("Aug2000-July2001.txt", sep="\t", header=T)

z <- with(dat, zoo(cbind(NEE,SWC))) 

options("na.actions"=na.omit)

plot.zoo(z, ylab=c("NEE(umolm-2s-1)", "SWC(%)"), 
         col=c("black","blue"), xlab=c("Date"), lwd=2)
```

Secondly, I have also tried e.g.

```
abline(v=as.Date("13/10/2000"))
```

but it is not working. How do I add multiple vertical lines and how do I add my date format on the x-axis on a zoo plot?

I have a table with some of the columns as follows:
[image: table]

Comment: Date Hour DateTime DOY Precip SWC NEE
01.08.2000 00:00 01.08.2000 00:00 214 0 8.2  -2.81
01.08.2000 00:30 01.08.2000 00:30 214.021 0 8.2  -2
01.08.2000 01:00 01.08.2000 01:00 214.042 0 8.2  -1.5
01.08.2000 01:30 01.08.2000 01:30 214.063 0 8.2  -2.16
01.08.2000 02:00 01.08.2000 02:00 214.083 0 8.2  -2.75
01.08.2000 02:30 01.08.2000 02:30 214.104 0 8.2  -1.86

Comment: Please use `dput(z)` and post the answer here to make your code reproducible.